# How to parse a JSON array of objects using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a Json response as follows:

```
   {
      "data": {
        "date": "7 Apr 2022",
        "employee": [
          {
            "id": [
              "1288563656"
            ],
            "firstname": [
              "Mohammed"
            ],
            "lastname": [
              "Ali"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I am trying to create a POJO called Employee and map it to the "employee" attribute in the JSON response.

This is what I did as an attempt:

**Employee.java**

```
public class Emoloyee {
    private Integer[] id;
    private String[] firstname;
    private String[] lastname;
    
    public Employee(Integer[] id, String[] firstname, String[] lastname){
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    
    public Employee(){
        
    }
    
    public Integet[] getId(){
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Integer[] id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String[] getFirstname(){
        return firstname;
    }
    
    public void setFirstname(String[] firstname){
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    
    public String[] getLastname(){
        return lastname;
    }
    
    public void setLastname(String[] lastname){
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    
}
```

Using Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
URL jsonUrl = new URL("[API_URL]");
final ObjectNode node = mapper.readValue(jsonUrl, ObjectNode.class);
Employee[] employees = mapper.treeToValue(node.get("data").get("employee"), Employee[].class);
```

When I execute the app, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type 'long' from Array value (toke 'JsonToken.START_ARRAY')
```

As you may noticed, I am not interested of the *date* attribute, I only need to get the values of the employee and create an Employee object out of it.

Comment: The id is a string array but you're using an Integer array

Comment: You need to change ```Integer[] id```  into ```String[] id``` into Employee class.
Into JSON format ```"property": "12342" //is string``` and ```"property": 12342 //is integer```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Employee` POJO should look like this:

```
@JsonProperty("id")
private final List<String> ids;
@JsonProperty("firstname")
private final List<String> firstNames;
@JsonProperty("lastname")
private final List<String> lastNames;

@JsonCreator
public Employee(@JsonProperty(value = "id") List<String> ids, @JsonProperty(value = "firstname") List<String> firstNames, @JsonProperty(value = "lastname") List<String> lastNames) {
    this.ids = ids;
    this.firstNames = firstNames;
    this.lastNames = lastNames;
}

//getters code
```

Then, you have an object `Data`:

```
@JsonProperty("date")
private final String date;
@JsonProperty("employee")
private final List<Employee> employees;

@JsonCreator
public Data(@JsonProperty(value = "date") String date, @JsonProperty(value = "employee") List<Employee> employees) {
    this.date = date;
    this.employees = employees;
} 

//getters code
```

Finally, the whole `Answer` that you want to parse has this shape:

```
@JsonProperty("data")
private final Data data;

@JsonCreator
public Answer(@JsonProperty(value = "data") Data data) {
    this.data = data;
} 

//getter code
```

Once you have defined these 3 classes, then you will be able to do:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Answer answer = objectMapper.readValue(yourStringAnswer, Answer.class);
```

Note: in your question, you are trying to parse an `URL` to an `ObjectNode`. I hardly doubt you would be able to do that.
I guess you want to perform the HTTP request to the `URL`, then getting the response stream and that's what you want to parse into `Answer` (not the URL itself).

Also, a few notes on the API response (in case you own it and so you can act on it):

- All the lists would be more naturally declared with a plural name (e.g. `employee` should be `employees`)
- The list of `ids` are numeric but are returned as strings. Also, why an employee would have a list of ids, and not a single id?
- Why would an employee have a list of first names and last names? Shouldn't this be a simple string each (even if composed by more than one name)?
- Use camel case (`firstName`, not `firstname`)
- I don't see the point of putting everything into `data`, it may simply be the response containing `date` and `employees`